# Markdown lint tool

Tags: markdown, validation, lint

The only one I could find: https://github.com/mivok/markdownlint, but not sure how mature it is.

As usual:

- the more cross platform the better
- the more free the better

I want this to enforce [my style guide](http://www.cirosantilli.com/markdown-styleguide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdast-lint https://github.com/wooorm/mdast-lint has come out, and it looks like a serious possibility.

You can configure it both per repository, and globally, and it covers many of the style guide points I wanted in my style guide.

Comment: The style guide by Ciro is available at http://www.cirosantilli.com/markdown-style-guide/.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint), because there is the VS Code plugin [markdownlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint), which seamlessly integrates in the IDE.

One can include a `.markdownlint.yml` file in the root of the repository to put global configurations:

```
default: true

# Allow arbitrary line length
#
# Reason: We apply the one-sentence-per-line rule. A sentence may get longer than 80 characters, especially if links are contained.
#
# Details: https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/Rules.md#md013---line-length
MD013: false
```

One can also put rules inside a Markdown file:

```
<!-- markdownlint-disable-file MD013 -->
```

All rules are available at https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/Rules.md#rules

There is also a [CLI tool](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint-cli2#markdownlint-cli2), a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint-cli2-action) (and another [GitHub Action](https://github.com/actionshub/markdownlint))